# Calling R Script from PHP/Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, r, d3.js, c3.js

I'm building a website with HTML/CSS/PHP/JavaScript which provide analytics graph. My database contain ~5,000,000 rows and I would like to use R to provide more complex and detailed graph about my data. My  problem is the website is already coded, so I would like to call the R script from PHP or JavaScript with input, get the return data in PHP or Javascript, then render the data in C3.js or D3.js. I looked on internet, but I'm lost about Shiny, HTMLWidget, OpenCPU, etc... I have no idea which one could fit for my need. I don't want to build a Dashboard from R, but use the capacity of R and return the result. If someone could tell me which path I should use to do that ? A secured way which is not limited to 50 request at the same time because it will be used in production

Thanks